# Variance calculation for a nonlinear combination of random variables

Tags: variance, covariance

How do a find the variance of a nonlinear combination of random variables. Say I want to find the variance of the quantity

$$\hat{\beta} = AB\exp(AC) + C$$

in function of the variances and covariances of A, B and C, which are known. Consider A, B and C estimators, with also values of their estimates available. What is ${\rm Var}(\hat{\beta})$?

Comment: I don't see why any symbolic software such as Mathematica wouldn't work?

Comment: I think Stata can do this with the `lincom` command.

Comment: @AdamO Thanks for your suggestion, but that one only returns numeric values

Comment: @AdamO I am guessing you meant `nlcom`. However, that will only work after an actual estimation command, rather taking an immediate argument.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov yes thank you, I don't use Stata often. Is it not possible to fit a multivariate regression with A, B, and C to obtain their covariance matrix and means as a multivariate normal ML estimate?

Comment: @AdamO It sounds like the OP already has those and wants software to give an analytic expression in terms of those quantities, rather a numeric answer.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov ok, another interpretation of the question (what I thought) is that the *user* expresses the algebraic quantity they desire to estimate, and the software derives a numerical expression for the Jacobian and covariance matrix and calculates the value numerically. R can do this but not what you say.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. The answer is actually very simple. It relies on multivariate delta method, which I was not aware of. This requires just first order symbolic derivation, which indeed any symbolic software can do.

Comment: @Knarpie, do you know the derivation? Would you want to post it as an answer, if this thread were reopened? Asking for software is off topic here, but asking for the derivation isn't.

Comment: @gung Yes please. I thought I had a software issue, but it turns out my understanding of the stats was lacking. I removed the part on the software, even though I disagree about it being off topic. When the questions get so technical, only statisticians will be able to point you to the right software. Also the wide interest in this question shows that it is useful to many.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the original question was asking for a software, the "hard" part is in statistical theory. The answer is called the multivariate delta method, which states that, given a variance-covariance matrix

$$V = \begin{bmatrix} 
\sigma^2_{A}  & \sigma_{A, B} & \sigma_{A, C}\\ 
\sigma_{A, B} & \sigma^2_{B} & \sigma_{B, C} \\ 
\sigma_{A, C} & \sigma_{B, C} & \sigma^2_{C} & 
\end{bmatrix} $$

and defining the gradient of $\hat{\beta}$

$$\nabla \hat{\beta}(A,B,C) = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial A}\\
\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial B}\\
\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial C}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The required variance is approximately

$$Var(\hat{\beta}) \approx \nabla \hat{\beta}^t V \nabla \hat{\beta}$$

Given the difficult formula for $\hat{\beta}$, finding the gradient is the "difficult" part, but indeed any symbolic software is able to carry out this symbolic derivation.

Comment: The delta method is an approximation, an important point to note. The delta method *does* work in all scenarios, and Mathematica can find the derivatives. The question could be made much more sophisticated by considering that certain linear and nonlinear combinations of RVs form known RVs whose variance could be expressed exactly.

Comment: First, the delta method is an approximation -- and it may not necessarily be a good approximation. Second, you are seeking the answer in terms of the known variances and covariances of $A$, $B$ and $C$. It is not transparent to me that the delta method will provide a solution in terms of the known variances and covariances. Third, given your functional form [with exp($AC$) ],  it will not be possible to provide a general solution just in terms of the variances and covariances of $A$, $B$ and $C$. Even without the exponent, say $Z = A B C +C$ it would be tough to express $Var(Z)$ as requested.

Comment: @wolfies I agree to your first point. Concerning your second and third: I modified the question such that also estimates of A, B and C are available, which will also be present in the final solution for the variance. Does this address your concerns?